# For those of you familiar with publishing apps on Google Play, I have a question about app compatibility?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm was just hoping to get a few possible solutions.

**So here's my problem:**

I created a project and selected **5.0 Lolipop** as the the minimum system need to operate my app. Now I thought this meant that all phones that had 5.0 Lolipop installed  (>85%) or more recent would be able to run my app. My phone is a Motorola G7 Power and has all the latest updates and the apps I create run very smoothly on it, but when I ask my friends to try the app with their Galaxy phones (recent models) it crashes 100% of the time upon opening the app. My friends with Huwuawai phones (Sorry, still can't spell it) can open the app, but are missing a few buttons. My app is just a random facts generator, where you tap on a button and new text appears. (Very VERY basic coding).

Are there any settings I'm missing? or possibly exporting it the wrong way?

[image: Or maybe something wrong with the version setup?]

I really appreciate the help, thank you in advance.

Comment: We can only guessing the problem without the error log. As @Merthan E says, you can see the error log from `Google Play Console -> All Application -> Your App -> Android Vitals -> ANRs & Crashes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no problems with your Gradle file (at least with the part that you’ve shared).

The fact that app is missing some of the buttons on Huawei phone might be because of the screen size or Dpi of the phone. So try running your app on emulators like Nexus S (although don’t try to make UI perfect for such screen size, but make sure every widget/view is present and fits on the screen).

With Samsung phone, it’s better to plug it in and see the logs. It’s normal for app to crush on some phones.

Lastly I’d recommend you getting a middle range phone that does run on non stock OS and non Android One OS. You’ll be surprised how many bugs can occur which are specific to OS or even just a version of OS.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Turns out a lot of my elements in my app were still at around 3000px x 2400px for a silly background and a lot of other high resolution images. After reducing them to the appropriate size it runs smoothly on the other phones now. Just as a side question: I used the xml editor to reduce a 2000px image button to 150dpi, is that something that should just be avoided in general?

Comment: Always use dp and sp for view sizes. Yet, prefer using wrap content over fixed sizes or use a constraint layout with match constraint view size (it’s when you set height/width to 0dp and assign 2 vertical/horizontal constraints)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't connect the phones and check the logs try using some Crashreporting tools, for example Play Console has the ANR/Crashes Tab where you might see stuff.

Apart from that Firebase (Crashlytics) also shows you crashes.